# What are the advantages of using data- rather than x- prefix for custom attributes?

Tags: html, angularjs

AngularJS documentation [says](https://code.angularjs.org/1.0.8/docs/guide/directive) `Optionally the directive can be prefixed with x-, or data- to make it HTML validator compliant.`.

Example markup:

1. no prefix: `<input ng-model="name">`
2. `data-` : `<input data-ng-model="name">`
3. `x-` : `<input x-ng-model="name">`

The `x-` prefix is faster to type than `data-`, but the tutorials I have seen used either no prefix or `data-`, so my question is: are there any reasons I might want to use `data-` rather than `x-`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The advantage of using a `data-` prefix rather than an `x-` prefix is that `data-` prefixes are guaranteed to remain available to authors as they like, whereas an `x-` prefix might one day be used for a browser-specific purpose, possibly conflicting with yours. Note that `x-` are not conforming according to HTML5.

Comment: But they ARE conforming to HTML 5.1

Comment: @richremer, no, 11 August 2013 version of [HTML 5.1 Nightly](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/) still says `x-` must not be used in document and adds an explicit note that they are non-conforming.

Answer (score 9):

`data-` is a [standardized part](http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/) [of the HTML5 spec](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/dom.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-%2a-attributes). Semantically it's the best way to go.

Comment: It also comes with specific DOM implementations that you just don't have access to with non-standard prefixes.

Comment: From the [spec](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/dom.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-%2a-attributes), "Custom data attributes are intended to store custom data private to the page or application, for which there are no more appropriate attributes or elements." Much more semantic (i.e. _meaningful_) to use a `data-attr` for custom data than to use `x-` or anything else.

Comment: Actually, according to HTML 5.1, the x- prefix is specifically designed for use by vendor extensions.  Angular even follows the laid out convention of x-vendor-feature.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid conflicts between your application attributes and future attributes that could be defined in HTML, the w3.org defined and normalized a specific scheme, the `data-*` attribute. See [the norm](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/elements.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-attributes).

Use it

- to reduce the risk of incompatibilities
- to let other coders and tools recognize that those attributes contain application specific data

Besides, using the normalized data attribute lets you use the [element.dataset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.dataset) property and  some libraries, for example jQuery, provide you specific utilities.