# declaring angular directives in markup

Tags: html, angularjs

What is the best practice for declaring directives on a HTML page. Per the http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/pagination the directive is shown as so

```
 <pagination total-items="bigTotalItems" ng-model="bigCurrentPage" max-size="maxSize" class="pagination-sm" boundary-links="true" rotate="false" num-pages="numPages"></pagination>
```

per this stackoverflow question [What are the advantages of using data- rather than x- prefix for custom attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17154830/what-are-the-advantages-of-using-data-rather-than-x-prefix-for-custom-attribut)

a better way of representing this directive would be as follows & conforms to [HTML5 specifications](http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/)

```
<div data-pagination data-total-items="totalItems" data-ng-model="currentPage" data-max-size="5" class="pagination-sm" data-boundary-links="true" data-rotate="false" data-ng-change="pageChanged()"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML validation isn't all that important. Sometimes they can be safely ignored. However just by adding a 'data-' prefix on all attributes, the editor would stop complaining about invalid html.

read more about it [here](http://thejeffwhitfield.com/blog/angularjs-and-html-validation/)

Answer (score 1):

Both are the same -> [angular directives](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive).
Use the shorter one.

Comment: I know both do the same thing - that's not my question, I'm talking about best practices - why should i use the "shorter one"- can you substantiate your answer

Answer (score 0):

data-ng-model = "user.name" and ng-model="user.name" provide you with the same outcome. You can use either. You can replace 'data' with 'x' and get the same outcome as well. You add the 'data' prefix to have them validated by html5 validators.